# Unable to connect to camera AVD

Tags: camera, avd-manager

I am trying to use my laptop's webcam in my android virtual device. however everytime I start the device I get error message as -

```
emulator: ERROR: cmd_camera_device_start_capturing: Unable to set video format: 0
```

My config.ini file for the device looks like -

```
hw.camera=yes
hw.camera.back=webcam0
hw.camera.front=webcam0
```

First line I added after reading upon some blog, however it doesn't work without first line also.

PS: Webcam flashes couple of times and them it gives this error. Although the android device loads up but camera app doesn't function mentioning "Can't connect to camera service".

Also... simulated camera works.

Any suggestions.

**EDIT**
Already done suggested changes as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850162/android-emulator-not-using-webcam-in-android-studio still no success.